# Aptana 3 and PHP 5.4 new array format

Tags: php, arrays, syntax, aptana

There is anyway to do that Aptana don't mark like errors syntax the new array shorthand?

I found this ticket, for one year ago, and still is open

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-7166?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

Comment: I would say that if you found the issue, they are already aware of the problem. As this is more like a bug report, I would suggest you to post a comment there.

Answer (score 1):

There is new version 3.6.0 out that support PHP 5.4. You can download it from website

Answer (score 0):

On Apatana Studio 3, right click your project. Click "Properties" from the drop down menu. Go to "PHP Development" then select PHP 5.4x or higher.